# strange behavior of 'echo' in 'env' bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, echo

When I am trying echo variable inside 'env' command I got nothing, but I can see it using 'printenv' command:

```
root@devel:~# env xxx=23 echo $xxx

root@devel:~# env xxx=23 printenv | grep xxx
xxx=23
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed exactly the same thing. It is somewhat disturbing when you're used to most of the recent languages that got lazyeval

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
env xxx=23 echo $xxx
```

In the above, the shell evaluates `$xxx` before `env` is executed.  Thus, nothing is echoed.

In more detail, the shell sees the four words `env`, `xxx=23`, `echo` and `$xxx`. It interprets `env` as a command name and `xxx=23`, `echo`, and `$xxx` as three arguments which will be passed to the command `env`.  It evaluates `$xxx` **before** passing it to the command `env`.

By contrast, in the following, there are no shell variables for the shell to evaluate.  Instead `env` is executed with two arguments, `xxx=23` and `printenv`.  `env` sets the environment variable `xxx` and then executes `printenv`:

```
$ env xxx=23 printenv | grep xxx
xxx=23
```

Similarly, observe:

```
$ env xxx=23 sh -c 'echo $xxx'
23
```

Since `$xxx` is inside single-quotes, the shell does not evaluate it.  Instead is runs `env` with four arguments: `xxx=23`, `sh`, `-c`, and `echo $xxx`.  After `env` sets environment variable `xxx`, it executes `sh` with arguments `-c` and `echo $xxx`.  The `$xxx` is evaluated when `sh` is executed and hence it sees the variable `xxx`.

Answer (score 4):

When you run `env xxx=23 echo $xxx`,
the variable `xxx=23` becomes visible to the `echo` process during its execution.
But in `echo $xxx` the value of `$xxx` is not evaluated by `echo`,
it is evaluated by the currently executing shell.
And since the `env ...` invocation doesn't affect the current shell,
the value of `$xxx` is whatever it was before you executed this command (probably unset).

`echo` is not a good way to test the effect of `env`,
because you cannot make the `echo` command print a specific value defined in its environment.
Your example with `printenv` is better,
because it dumps the content of environment variables it knows about.
Another good test is what @john wrote in his answer,
invoking another shell and make the shell print a chosen environment variable.
Any program with the ability to print the content of environment variables would work.